# Remove Duplicates from Col X based on condition in Col Y

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a data frame in R, that has duplicates, in one of the columns, however I only want to remove the duplicate based on a specification in another column.

For Example:

DF:

```
X    J    Y
1    2    3
2    3    1
1    3    2
```

I want to remove rows, where `X` is a duplicate and  `= 3`.

DF:

```
X    J    Y
2    3    1
1    3    2
```

I have tried reading on `dplyr`, but have so far only been unable to get the desired result.

Comment: There are two 'X' columns. I assume it is the first one, right?

Comment: If you want to remove rows where X is duplicate and Y is 3, then why is the 3rd row in expected output

Comment: your right, the third column should be Z, i will fix that right away

Comment: Also, your decription and output is conflicting

Comment: @akrun, you are again correct, I have updated this, your solution works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create the condition to condition with `duplicated` and the equality operator

```
subset(df1, !((duplicated(X)|duplicated(X, fromLast = TRUE)) & Y == 3))
#  X J Y
#2 2 3 1
#3 1 3 2
```

---

If we need to remove the whole group of rows of 'X' if there is any value of 'Y' is 3, then

```
library(dplyr)
df1t %>% 
     group_by(X) %>%
     filter(! 3 %in% Y) #or
     # filter(all(Y != 3))
```

Comment: Hello akrun, it worked on that small example however when i expand it out to
    X <- c(1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
    J <- c(2,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1)
    Y <- c(3,2,1,2,1,2,3,1,3)

     df1t = data.frame(X, J, Y)  

    df2t <- subset(df1t, !((duplicated(X)|duplicated(X, fromLast = TRUE)) & Y == 3))

it return the duplicates where Y = 3, i want to remove where Y = 3, and keep the others

Comment: @Pythonuser what is the expected output here

Comment: I will edit the original question, ass i can not figure out how to, display it in the comments

Comment: @Pythonuser  Can you try `library(dplyr);df1t %>% group_by(X) %>% filter(n() == 1| Y != 3)`

Comment: @Pythonuser Can u please edit your post and update the expected output